# Transform class method from callback flow to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, callback

I have the following sample code,

```
class GetResultsFromDatabase{
    results : SiteTable[];
    db : AccessDatabase;

    constructor(){
      this.db = new AccessDatabase();
    }

    getAllLevelsSites(){
      this.db.getSitesDb(this.fullFillSites);

    }

    private fullFillSites(data : SiteTable[]){
           this.results= data; 
           this.db.getUrlsDb(this.fullFillUrls);
    }

    private fullFillUrls(data : UrlsTable[]){
        data.map( (current) => this.results[this.results.findIndex(obj => obj.id = 
        current.token)].urlTable = current );
    }
}
```

If some code outside class calls the method "getAllLevelsSite" i want to return the complete results array with all the values fullfilled (after the last "fullFillUrls function complete).

The "db" object uses the mysql library so all the methods works only with callbacks.Which options do i have ? Is it possible to create any kind of Promise in getAllLevelsSite method in a way that the code that is calling it can use async await syntax ? Or the only way is to pass one callback function to the method getAllLevelsSite ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: I think it would be best to convert `AccessDatabase` from callbacks to Promises. Besides, this code is riddled with bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not provide impl. for `getSitesDb` so will guess how the callback looks like...

```
getAllLevelsSites() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.getSitesDb(this.fullFillSites, (arr, err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
         resolve(arr);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Now wherever you are consuming this method you can use `await`

Answer (score 0):

Untested (so I could be wrong), but rewriting `getAllLevelsSites` method to something like the below might work:

```
  getAllLevelsSites(): Promise<SiteTable[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.db.getSitesDb(resolve);
    });
  }
```

Based on the signature of `fullFillSites`, I've assumed that the callback passed to `this.db.getSitesDb` will be invoked with at least one argument (of type `SiteTable[]`).

Since `getAllLevelsSites` returns in a promise (in this code above), you should be able to then use `async`/`await` syntax.

---

Unrelated: You use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over `data` in `fullFillUrls`, but don't do anything with the array that `map` returns. Seems like you should swap `map` out for `forEach`.